# Picture of Captain Future's Otho that proves he is a robot

Tags: comics, captain-future

[image: Otho]

The character [Otho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Future#Characters) ("Otto" in the German series) is, according to Wikipedia, a green-skinned android. But actually it is never shown that he is a robot.

Does the series or comics show any pictures or stills with a scene, that proves that he is a robot and that he is green?

On this picture from http://www.robertweinberg.net/captainfuture.htm it seems like he is green:
[image]

But I am not sure, if that supposed to be Otho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the explanation: in the second part of the first Episode there is explained how Otho and greg were built:

There you see definitely that Otho IS a robot:

[image]

Comment: I can't watch the link from germany, but my impression was, that they make a difference between robot (Greg, machine, metal) and Android, whatever it ist. He is artificially created, but more of an artificial lifeform (base on rubber?) as a machine. At least that was my impression when I watched it as a child.

Answer (score 5):

He is an android with shape-shifting capabilities, as shown in these screenshots below from the 1st episode of the "Megara" arc of the German cut. The "green-skinned" seems to be an error in Wikipedia, as his skin is obviously not green in the anime, and according to [these scans](http://www.robertweinberg.net/captainfuture.htm) from the original novels his skin is supposed to be white.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: OK, that proves that he is a 'shapeshifter', but still no prove he is an android. And I added a Cover of a Comic, where Otho seems to be on it

Comment: @rubo77: look at the page I linked to. It has scans from column attached to the novels that describes Otho in detail. I very explicitly says that he is an android and his skin is white. The cover is also there, and there is another cover where his skin seems more yellowish. I'd say  the textual description of the author trumps the covers, where the coloring may just have been added by the artist because it's easier to paint that way.

Comment: it is strange, cause it is exactly from that page, where it sais in the text at the top "Otho, a green-skinned android", but I also think he has normal white skin. I was hoping to find a picture or still from the series too, where Otho looks more like an android, but he always looks like human

Comment: @rubo77  An android is defined as a robot that looks human.  (in science fiction) a robot with a human appearance.
synonyms: robot, automaton, cyborg, droid, bot
"a space station run by androids"
So by science fiction definition Commander Data is about as non human as an android can look.